# Sets in product $\sigma$-algebras that cannot be written as a product of measurable sets in the factors.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am aware that not every set in a product $\sigma$-algebra can be represented as a product of measurable sets in the factors (e.g., take the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$), but this seems weird to me. The unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is not a product of open sets, but it is a countable union of products of open sets.

It just seems counter-intuitive to me that you can have a union of products of measurable sets that cannot be written as a product of measurable sets in the factors. Is there something funky that's going on when you're taking unions of product sets that's responsible for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following questions:

*Is the set of all products $A\times B$, where $A$ and $B$ are measurable sets in their respective $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ on $X$ and $Y$, itself a $\sigma$-algebra* on $X\times Y$?

*What is the definition of the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B}$ on $X\times Y$*?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing's funky; you should instead  update your intuition.

The fact that not every subset of a product of sets $A\times B$ can be written as $C\times D$ for some $C\subseteq A$ and $D\subseteq B$ basically amounts to saying "*there exist shapes other than rectangles*". Everything else in your question about measurability is ultimately irrelevant to this observation.